# How can I get past the loading screen?

Tags: terratech

I downloaded the game TerraTech on Steam and when I try to play it, the game never gets past the welcome screen. What can I do to get past this and play the game?

Comment: I have had the same problem on my MacBook Pro. So I read the reviews of TerraTech on Steam, and some people had the same problem as us.I allowed access for assistive devices for Steam after reading that it was only a risk to do that if you did not know what you were downloading. That still didn't work, so I went on Google and came across this. Until you tell me what device you were using, I cannot help you. However, I do know TerraTech works on PC, and I used to play it on PC.

Comment: This is game-independent; but you could try re-verifying the game files.  This link provides instructions:  https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335